# code igniter appending IS NULL after WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using code igniter way to write query. However, it is not working and when I firebug it, showng me IS NULL added in my query.

```
$select_fields  = "id,name,created_by,keywords";
$where_field    = "FIND_IN_SET('$id','keywords')";

$this -> db_social -> select($select_fields);
$this -> db_social -> from('user_collection1');
$this -> db_social -> where($where_field);
$query  = $this->db_social->get();
```

Error is showing query like this

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `created_by`, `keywords` FROM `user_collection1` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('11','keywords') IS NULL
```

Comment: Try: `$this->db_social->where($where_field, null, false);` (example from [the documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html)). Btw, don't have spaces in your object calls like this: `$this -> db_social -> ...`. It makes the code much much harder to read.

Comment: if you remove `where` clause, is it working or not?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL function you using has this syntax, `FIND_IN_SET(needle, haystack)`. The second argument is a string and the string you provide is "keywords". Clearly the string "11" is not in the string "keywords".

I think you'll get what you need by not using the `db->where()` function at all.
Give this a try.

```
$select  = "id,name,created_by,keywords WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$id', keywords)";

$this->db_social->select($select);
//don't need the ->from call since this uses a single table, put that name in ->get
$query  = $this->db_social->get('user_collection1');
```